# How to create a swing application using maven?

Tags: eclipse, swing, maven-2

I was trying to start new swing application using maven,
so I started searching on maven documentation but (frustratingly) found no clue. So I'm asking:

- what is the archetype used?
- what are the dependencies?
- how to build swing app in maven [is there is plugin to do so]?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> - what is the archetype used?

A swing application is a standard JAR so just use the standard archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
                       -DartifactId=myswingapp     \
                       -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

> - what are the dependencies?

If you plan to use the standard [Swing](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/swing/) API only, there aren't no extra dependencies to declare. But if you want to use things like [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/), [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), [SwingX](http://swinglabs.org/docs/project/maven-swingx.jsp), [Flamingo](https://flamingo.dev.java.net/), [SwingFX](https://swingfx.dev.java.net/) etc then you'll have to add the appropriate artifacts and repositories. But there is no universal answer to your question.

> - how to build swing app in maven [is there is plugin to do so ]?

A Swing app is not really particular. I would maybe just consider using [Java Web Start](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp) (and the [Maven Webstart plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/)) or maybe a cross platform installer like [IzPack](http://izpack.codehaus.org) (and the [Maven IzPack Plugin](http://izpack.codehaus.org/izpack-maven-plugin/)). But you have time for that, you need an application before :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if you are only using Swing (I mean if you do not want additional features such as [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) for example), then you will not need to add specific information in your `pom.xml` file, as everything needed for Swing development is already embedded in the JDK.

Concerning the build process, there is also nothing specific additions here. However, you may need be interesed in:

- [Creating an executable JAR](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html).
- [Making a big JAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), that also contains all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Check these links if you have problems finding documentation about maven [Better builds with Maven](http://www.maestrodev.com/better-build-maven) and [Maven: The Definitive Guide](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/maven-the-definitive-guide-split-into-two-books/). Then you will figure out that you can build any kind of app like swing using maven. Maven is not a framework is project management and comprehension tool.

***Note:*** Maven: The Definitive Guide was split into two books. The link goes to the blog post that links to both of them.