# Is Maven the right coice for a simple plain (Hello World) java project? (No J2EE, No Springboot...)?

Tags: maven

I want to create a simple java desktop application.

Now i asked myself how to start, should i use maven?
Or is maven much more for projects in the j2ee, springboot space?
How to start?

Comment: `maven` will help adding dependencies in your project easily and your raw code will be portable. Better to use it.

Comment: Well do you expect that it stays a rather simple hello world project or do you think it will grow to something bigger in the nearest future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the stack you want to use for your desktop app (and keep in mind, that java is more and more a platform for non-desktop stuff)

- pure Swing UI: see [How to create a swing application using maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191656/how-to-create-a-swing-application-using-maven)
- [Griffon](http://griffon-framework.org) you can use an maven archetype for this see [griffon maven archetypes](https://bintray.com/griffon/griffon-archetypes)

in general: maven is always the right choice but it does not restrict you to any stack